# How to write a Boolean value using javax.xml.stream Interface XMLStreamWriter interface

Tags: java, xml, oop

while generating a file, I wish to write code as shown in below pseudo code

```
String value;
Boolean flagVlaue;
XMLStreamWriter write;
if(value is string)
{
  writer.writeCharacters(value); 
}else{
  writer.{I_dont_know_which_method_to_use_here}(flagValue);
}
```

I wish to find out a way to write a way to write a way to write it as Boolean. I can not write it as string literal as The third party software use to read the file expects it as Boolean not as string the the file.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "The third party software use to read the file expects it as Boolean not as string"? How does the XML look? If you know that, you can easily create the right string for `true` and `false`. In serialized XML it is simply a string.

Comment: @Vanje, absolutely correct. It's not the processor generating the xml but the input file itself which has invalid data. where data is given in single quotes and hence the third party software "arelle" is reading it as string and expects boolean. (expects `false` but gets`'false'`). upvote for taking time to share your valuable thoughts.

Comment: I don't think, I understand the problem. Can you edit your question and include an XML snippet which would be accepted by the third party software? As long it is well formed XML it should be no problem to create such XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply the writeCharacters method as follow:

```
  writer.writeCharacters(Boolean.toString(false));
```

Regards,